# Problem with WSDL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to create a PHP soap server based on a WSDL I was given to modify for our purposes.  The problem is coming in the form of the WSDL file, I think.  When I bring it up to test it here: http://www.validwsdl.com/, the response dies out and tells me that the function isn't present.

The idea is that the expected input is 4 items, those 4 items will be put into the function, used, and 4 other items will be returned.  I cut out everything but the return in my sample here, but the idea should still work.

This is my PHP code:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
 $server = new SoapServer("InventoryInquiry.wsdl");
 $server->addFunction("GetInventoryStatus");
 $server->handle(); 


function GetInventoryStatus($request) {
$dealerBranch = 1;//default branch to 1
$inStock = 0;//default in stock to 0
$cantTrack = 0; //used to check if branch is tracked
$estDeliveryTime = "";
$estDeliveryDate = "";
$deliveryLocation = "";


  return array(
          'InStock' => $inStock,
          'EstDeliveryDate' =>$estDeliveryDate,
          'EstDeliveryTime'=> $estDeliveryTime,
          'DeliveryLocation' => $dealerBranch
          );
```

}

And this is my wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">  
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php">
      <s:element name="GetInventoryStatus">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DealerCode" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SupplierCode" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PartNumber" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetInventoryStatusResponse">       
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InStock" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstDeliveryDate" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstDeliveryTime" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DeliveryLocation" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
  </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>  
  <wsdl:message name="InventoryRequestRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetInventoryStatus" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="InventoryRequestResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetInventoryStatusResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>  
  <wsdl:portType name="InventoryStatusPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="InventoryRequest">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:InventoryRequestRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:InventoryRequestResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>  
  <wsdl:binding name="InventoryStatusBinding" type="tns:InventoryStatusPortType">
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="InventoryRequest">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php#InventoryStatus" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:InventoryStatus"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:InventoryStatus"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>  
  <wsdl:service name="InventoryStatus">
    <wsdl:port name="InventoryStatusPort" binding="tns:InventoryStatusBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>      
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm quite new to this web services in general, and I'm having a heck of a time with this.  Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ghostJago noted, you should use use "document" style not "rpc" ("document/literal" is the preffered style).

But also watch your namespaces (I see you use `urn:InventoryStatus` and `http://www.elennox.net/server1.php`. Which one is it?).

I think something like this is what your are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php" 
    name="InventoryStatusService">

    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php">
            <s:element name="GetInventoryStatus">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DealerCode" type="s:string" />
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SupplierCode" type="s:string" />
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PartNumber" type="s:string" />
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:int" />
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="GetInventoryStatusResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InStock" type="s:int" />
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstDeliveryDate" type="s:string" />
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstDeliveryTime" type="s:string" />
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DeliveryLocation" type="s:string" />
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="InventoryRequestRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetInventoryStatus" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="InventoryRequestResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetInventoryStatusResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="InventoryStatusPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="InventoryRequest">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:InventoryRequestRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:InventoryRequestResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="InventoryStatusBinding" type="tns:InventoryStatusPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="InventoryRequest">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php#InventoryStatus" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="InventoryStatus">
        <wsdl:port name="InventoryStatusPort" binding="tns:InventoryStatusBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This will produce the following request/response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ser="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:GetInventoryStatus>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:DealerCode>...</ser:DealerCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:SupplierCode>...</ser:SupplierCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:PartNumber>...</ser:PartNumber>
         <ser:Quantity>...</ser:Quantity>
      </ser:GetInventoryStatus>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ser="http://www.elennox.net/server1.php">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:GetInventoryStatusResponse>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:InStock>...</ser:InStock>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:EstDeliveryDate>...</ser:EstDeliveryDate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:EstDeliveryTime>...</ser:EstDeliveryTime>
         <ser:DeliveryLocation>...</ser:DeliveryLocation>
      </ser:GetInventoryStatusResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also, it is good etiquette :D to declare faults to your operations (which will contain details in case something goes wrong).

Good luck!

Comment: Both of those answers helped a lot. Thank you both!  The link from ghostJago was hugely informative.  And the stuff there from dpb seems a big help too.  I'll test it out later today when I get a chance, but this stuff makes a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

try changing both the style attributes to the same value, so

```
<soap:binding style='document' transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
```

You can use either **document** or **rpc** for the style.  This link describes the various different methods for style and use combinations:

[Which style of WSDL should I use](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/)

Its pretty technical though so hopefully setting both the style references to the same value should sort your issue.  In the past I've only really used **document/literal** *or* **rpc/encoded**.